# In terms of resource allocation in kubernetes, is Mi the same as MiB

Tags: kubernetes

Sounds like a silly question but I see Mi in yml files but what I'm familiar with is MiB. Are the two the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the official reference, `Mi` is just a prefix so the actual unit will be `MiB`.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-memory-resource/#memory-units